# Vim Vundle not allowing plugins to be installed due to errors

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I have Ubuntu Studio 19.04 installed recently. I am trying to revive my installation of vim. I installed it thru apt-get, and and have installed Vundle. The problem is now, I have no useable plugins. It appears to crap out on the :PluginSearch colon command, so that Vundle can't list or install plugins. Below are the messages that was flashed on my instance of vim when I tried PluginSearch. I managed to catch "flashed" error message on video and took a screenshot of a frame from the video.

A split second after that message, I was returned to a split window, which had an empty plugin list, but below it said "1 plugins found".

I tried to go online to see how to solve this, but no one had quite this error, and no provided solution resulting in overcoming the plugin installation problem, after hours trying them.

If anyone can offer suggestions, such as what parts of Vundle these errors are coming from, and possible workarounds, I would appreciate it.

```
=============
Flashed error messages follow:
Error detected while processing function vundle#scripts#all[3]..<SNR>31_load_scripts:
Line 7:
E15: Invalid exression: <html>^M
E15: Invalid exression: <html>^M
Error detected while processing function vundle#scripts#all:
Line 10:
E686: Argument of reverse() must be a list
Error detected  while processing function vundle#scripts#all[10]..vundle#scripts#view:
Line 1:
E712: Argument of map() must be a list or Dictionary
Error detected  while processing function vundle#scripts#all[10]..vundle#scripts#view:
Line 15:
E745: Using a List as a Number
E116: Invalid arguments for function append
```

Paul King

Comment: It appears you might not have set it up properly. Try installing afresh.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen What is "afresh"?

Comment: @jumpnett what I mean is, you should install it again starting from the beginning!

Comment: I thought "afresh" was an app, lol

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that apparently Vundle is a legacy package manager for vim, and when we use the PluginSearch function, it downloads available scripts lists from vim-scripts.org. A visit to the said address reveals that the website has been discontinued:

> This used to be a mirror of Vim's scripts site on Github.
>
> It was created to allow early package managers (such as Vim Update Bundles and Vundle) to install scripts straight from GitHub *.
>
> Now that most Vim scripts are developed on GitHub and installable straight from the source, I'm happy to say that there's no need for vim-scripts anymore.

Available scripts can now be found on https://www.vim.org/scripts/, and to install, just add `Plugin 'your-required-plugin'` in your `.vimrc` file somewhere `filetype off` and `filetype plugin indent on`.

**Walkthrough**
In your terminal instance, type `vim ~/.vimrc`. This will open the file if it exists, or create a new one if you save the changes. The following is what I have in my .vimrc, you can simply copy and paste it, and install the plugins of your choice below this comment: `" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle used Bundle instead of Plugin)`

```
syntax enable
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set autoindent

set nocompatible        " required
filetype off            " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#rc()

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/vimPlugins/')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle used Bundle instead of Plugin)
Plugin 'python-mode/python-mode'
Plugin 'Royal-Colorschemes'
Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'

" ...

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()       " required
filetype plugin indent on   " required
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!